# Why "RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" did not succeed?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

I don't want my nginx docker image to have `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` so I wrote a simple nginx dockerfile, mainly to add `RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

To my surprise it did not work. /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is still there.

Why and how do I delete it ?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy custom configuration file from the current directory
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY conf.d/node2 /etc/nginx/conf.d/node2
EXPOSE 80 8080
```

My docker-compose.yml for nginx service adds a name volumn

```
volumes:
- conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Update:

I finally found out that it is because I created a name volume in my docker-compose.yml that create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` so rm in dockerfile won't work at all. But why creating a name volume will result in creating `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ?

Update2:

With the second answer I got I finally figure out why. So `RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` did work. The problem is I used a volume in my docker-compose.yml that was created before I run `RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` and that volume has default.conf.

It happened like this, I first used a dockerfile without rm and run `docker-compose up`, then I added rm to it to rebuild the image and run `docker-compose up` again. But I never change my docker-compose.yml or clean my volume. So the file was there no matter how I build/rebuild my image.

After I deleted all the old volume (using *docker volume rm `docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true`*) it finally works.

I leave my question here instead of deleting it just in case someone else may make the same mistake like I did :$

Comment: If you are trying to run `nginx` with your custom `conf` file, there is a section at [https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) which tells you how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to get rid of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf, I didn't find how to do that in https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not clear at all. The official nginx image has the default.conf file, it doesn't matter from which OS you run it. I suspect you did not push the changes you did on your image in your registry.

Comment: I am quite sure I pushed it and the file is still there. That was why I asked this question in the first place

Comment: I tried to push the image on AWS ECS and Azure. Same results. Can you post your Dockerfile? Also the docker-compose file would help

Comment: sure, see my update.

Comment: It still works. Can you please post also your `docker-compose.yml`, if you use it. Otherwise, how do you start your container locally?

Comment: Yes I use docker-compose.yml.     volumes:
    - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158496/discussion-between-stefano-and-qiulang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volumes are a run time change to the filesystem. The build runs without your volume to create the image. Therefore the file is deleted in the image, but then you mount a volume in your container that has the file.

The fix is to either not use a volume so you can see the filesystem as it exists in the image, or you can delete the file from the volume. The following should work for cleaning the file from the volume:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${vol_name}:/target busybox rm /target/default.conf
```

Comment: Hi, "you mount a volume in your container that has the file" , but which container has that file? Because I already deleted it for the nginx container.

Comment: @Qiulang You deleted the file from the nginx image (build time), not from the container's volume that's mounted externally and replaces anything in the image at that directory location (run time).

Comment: that is the past I don't get! You can see in my dockerfile, not only did I delete default.conf, I also added a file node2, when I run my nginx image I found both default.conf and node2 are there, so it is not "replaces anything in the image at that directory location". And which container you were talking about exactly when you said: "not from the container's volume that's mounted externally"?

Comment: Which container? You'll have to tell me, I can't see your screen. Please update your question with the output from you either removing the file from the volume or removing the volume completely (as directed above), an inspect on the container, and an ls from inside the container of the directory so that we can further assist.

Comment: With your input, I finally figure out why (see my update). So I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're using your new image.

I tested it by simply creating a new Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

and I've executed the following commands:

```
docker build -t test-nginx .
docker run -it --name mynginx-instance test-nginx ls -la /etc/nginx/conf.d
docker rm mynginx-instance
```

Comment: and one way is to use `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`